How to access this website? (This site can’t provide a secure connection)
I cannot find any way of accessing websites which do not support the latest version of TLS. (At least I think this is what the issue is.)
The website I am trying to access is:

https://juliaacademy.com/p/introduction-to-machine-learning

I have tried

different browsers: Edge, Chrome, Firefox

There were supposedly some workarounds for Chrome where special sequences of characters could by typed and the webpage would magically be loaded. I've tried a few different suggestions, and none of those special character sequences ("cheat codes") appeared to work.
The full error shown by Chrome browser is this:
This site can’t provide a secure connection

juliaacademy.com uses an unsupported protocol.

ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH



It works fine in Firefox v. 131.0.3, using no VPN, and USA and Japan VPN servers. Perhaps your locale is an issue?

The website in question doesn't accept TLS at all. It rejects every TLS handshake, regardless of version, with the same "Handshake Failed" error. You can't force Chrome to bypass this because it's not Chrome that refuses to connect in the first place.

Ok interesting. How did you figure that out? Is this therefore a server side problem, with no way of "getting data out" of the site (at least until someone updates something on the server side) ?

@user3728501 It most definitely works here. Running openssl s_client -connect juliaacademy.com:443, it connected with TLSv1.3, TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384. Also, connecting using Vivaldi, it worked fine. Of course, it may be there was an issue which has now been fixed, or perhaps your ssl libs are not up to date.
